# Why don't I get System.Windows?

Tags: reference, visual-studio-2005, intellisense

When I type:

```
System.
```

I am expecting `Windows` to be one of the options available with the Intellisense, but it is not.

Why not?

Comment: what is the application you are working on windows/web/console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you don't have a reference to the correct assembly. You need to make that yourself if you have a console project for example.

You need to right click the references and add a new one:

```
System.Windows.Forms
```

See also [How to: Add or Remove References in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a reference in your project to System.Windows.Forms?

Writing a console app?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a Windows Forms project?
If so, you should have a reference to System.Windows.Forms added in your project references.

But for a class library (and probably eg console or ASP.NET project), you won't have this by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add reference.

go to -> Add Reference ".Net" -> "System.Windows.Forms".